# Put up an email signup on a website

Tags: bulk-email, newsletter

I want to set up an email newsletter for my site and want to have a subscribe box on the website.  What is the best free listserver host for someone sending weekly newsletter to a few hundred people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take your pick really :

[Mailchip](http://www.mailchimp.com)

[Campaign monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/)

[Aweber](http://www.aweber.com)

are some of the most popular, theres loads out there but mailchimp i found is the easiest to use, and its free for up to 10000(i think) emails a month.

A nice simple alternative, depending on what you want is [Tiny Letter](http://tinyletter.com/) (owned by mailchimp)

Comment: good suggestions.  I especially like Mailchimp

Comment: Mailchimp is the only service with a truly free plan.